# pls see php code below how can i edit so i can add facebook fanpage link and twitter

Tags: php, echo

pls see php code below how can i edit so i can add facebook fanpage link and twitter

```
<li></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo trim($options['facebook_url'],' ')!=''?$options['facebook_url']:'#'?>"  target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/twittericon.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo trim($options['twitter-url'],' ')!=''?$options['twitter-url']:'#'?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/facebooktext.gif" title="Follow us on Facebook" alt="Facebook" border="0"  /></a></li>
```

Comment: <a href="<?php echo trim($options['facebook_url'],' ')!=''?$options['facebook_url']:'#'?>"  target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/twittericon.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0" /></a>
<a href="<?php echo trim($options['twitter-url'],' ')!=''?$options['twitter-url']:'#'?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/facebooktext.gif" title="Follow us on Facebook" alt="Facebook" border="0"  /></a>

Comment: Edit your question. No one will read this comments.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Wordpress.

1. You can hard code your links by setting options keys to correct values like this (not recommended):

   `<?php 
   $options['facebook_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/facebook'; 
   $options['twitter-url'] = 'https://twitter.com/twitter';
   ?>
   <a href="<?php echo trim($options['facebook_url'],' ')!=''?$options['facebook_url']:'#'?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/facebooktext.gif" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook" border="0" /></a>
   <a href="<?php echo trim($options['twitter-url'],' ')!=''?$options['twitter-url']:'#'?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/twittericon.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0" /></a>`
2. If you hard coding you dont need to use php at all:

   `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/facebooktext.gif" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook" border="0" /></a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/twittericon.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0" /></a>`
3. You can set option "facebook_url" via admin interface depending on theme/plugins you use.

Comment: hi, i am using wordpress but i need to edit this php source file so i have no idea how to edit it so i posted here for help. my code as follow :                 <a href="<?php echo trim($options['facebook_url'],' ')!=''?$options['facebook_url']:'#'?>"  target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/twittericon.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0" /></a>

Comment: hi, nerijus based on the answer u gave , so i just follow your code for edition ?

Comment: can show me, i m not really familiar with php, thanks much

Comment: correct ?? <a href="<?php $options['facebook_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/facebook'; ?>"  target="_blank">

Comment: I added full snippet in answer. You should replace yours with it.

Comment: <a href="<?php $options['facebook_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/facebook'; ?>"  target="_blank">

Comment: <a href="<?php $options['twitter_url'] = 'https://www.twitter.com/gengood'; ?>"  target="_blank">

Comment: no. look at answer, not at comment. answer includes 3 options, first two are quick and dirty.

Comment: ``<a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/facebooktext.gif" alt="Follow us on Facebook" title="Follow us on Facebook" border="0" /></a>``

Comment: hi , i already look at the code but i not really understand , to be simple facebook 1 code, twitter 1 code , can separate then i try the code again

Comment: thanks so much for help, the above code u posted really useful, i just copy and paste and it working, going to try twitter now

Comment: here's twitter link example: ``<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/images/twittericon.gif" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" border="0" /></a>``. dont forget to mark correct answer, thanks